# How do you determine what is prompting "Sign in to iCloud" with a previously used Apple ID

Tags: macos, icloud, apple-id

I recently setup a new MacBook (running 13.4) and created a new Apple ID to use as a separate developer account. Once setup was completed, the first thing I did after logging in to the machine with the local account was to go into System Settings and log out of iCloud which at this point was associated with the new Apple ID as expected. I then logged into iCloud with my usual Apple ID. Everything works as expected. I have access to everything in iCloud, etc. but occasionally I get prompted to "Sign in to iCloud" for the developer account that I initially created.

[image: prompt that I am seeing]

Is there a way to find out what is triggering this prompt? If not, is there a way to make sure an Apple ID is wholly disassociated from a user on a computer?

***FOLLOW UP***: To stop the window from popping up randomly asking for the password of the Apple ID that is not currently logged into iCloud go to https://appleid.apple.com/ and remove the device (in this case my Mac Book Pro) from the devices associated to the account in question. This stops the pop up but doesn't answer the question of how to find out what is actually triggering the prompt or why.

Comment: I have had this issue for a while now. Could not find a fix. Even your fix didn't work for me. I suspect you are right though, that it must be something related to a root iCloud function that is somehow logged in separately from everything else.

Comment: I think I finally figured it out. Now that the OS itself is an app within the App Store there is an "owner" for the OS itself, the same as there would be for any app. That is, the app triggering this dialog is the OS itself. If you find the current version of the OS in the App Store and "Get" it, it will redownload and reinstall the current OS. This fixes the issue because the current logged in Apple ID now "owns" that version/install macOS. It's a silly solution, but the sealed system volume model that macOS now operates on makes it not really a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

I recently saw this where someone had an outdated (and inaccessible) email address still in their Messages account list; iCloud was signed in on multiple devices (iPhone and iPad), but the iCloud sign-in prompt on one was preventing it from syncing the correct settings from the other.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The Messages account list was a great thought and I immediately checked it just now but do not have the iCloud account that I'm getting prompted for listed. It _feels_ like this is what is happening but with maybe a different service/app. Since I immediately logged out of the iCloud account I created during setup on first launch it has to be a service/app that got setup during system setup but I can't find which one.